# Restart specific racoon tunnel

Tags: freebsd, vpn, ipsec

I have several **gif*** interfaces on my FreeBSD box. They are representing tunnels, encrypted using `racoon`+`ipsec`. If, at some moment, one of the tunnels hangs up, I am forced to reset `racoon` this way:

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/racoon restart
```

But in that case all tunnels are reset, which leads to a short absence of connectivity on all my tunnels (3-5 seconds, but nevertheless).

Is there any method to reset one specific gif tunnel, while not touching any other tunnels?

Answer (score 0):

You can force a single IPSec tunnel to reconnect by deleting the tunnels security association (SA).

Use this to find your current SAs:

```
# setkey -D
# setkey -DP
```

[man setkey (8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setkey&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+10.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)

Or maybe use [security/ipsec-tools](http://www.freshports.org/security/ipsec-tools)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something to help me with that and put in my .bash_login file

```
dtun()
{
  while read a b _ _ c _ 
     do c=${c#*=}
     echo "delete ${a%[*} ${b%[*} esp ${c%(*}; " | setkey -c
  done < <(setkey -D | grep $1 -A 1 | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/--/\n/g' )
}
```

Just call `dtun <IP>` to delete SAs